# How to parse json data and load it to django template

Tags: python, json, django, api, parsing

How would i parse it to load store address id and title from the api to the select option value ?

what i have tried so far

```
<select>
          {% for store in stores.store_address %}
          <option value="{{ store.store_address.id}}">{{ store.store_address.title}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

code in getting the data

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    stores = requests.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16tdlw').json()
    context['stores'] = stores
    return context
```

URL : https://api.myjson.com/bins/16tdlw (json data)

Template :

```
<select>
          {% for store in stores.store_address %}
          <option value="{{ store.store_address.id}}">{{ store.store_address.title}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your template to.

**Demo:**

```
<select>
    {% for store in stores %}
        {% for store_addres in stores.store_address %}
            <option value="{{ store_addres.id}}">{{ store_addres.title}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**Note:**

- `stores` is a list you need to iterate it and then access `store_address`.

Comment: have you tried checking the json link @Rakesh , there were still problem